# Windows Server 2003: Any disadvantages to moving website outside of wwwroot?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003

My boss recently asked me if I could move our website outside of the wwwroot folder and place it into "C:\MySite", on windows server 2003.  I tried doing so, and setting this up in IIS 6, but had no luck.  The website wouldn't start up, so I placed the site back into wwwroot.

So I have 2 questions: One, is there any disadvantage to moving a website outside of the wwwroot folder?  I found it peculiar the site works fine in wwwroot, but won't start outside of it...and two, if there's no disadvantage, how can I get IIS to run the website properly if outside wwwroot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple and easy. Follow the steps here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138

or http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5adfcce1-030d-45b8-997c-bdbfa08ea459.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

Site can be anywhere, especially  on local machine. Check if

- you copied all files to new location
- you changed location of the root of the site in IIS Manager (Start->run->inetmgr)
- check event log for any errors
- check if accoutn app pool for the site runs under have permissions to read from new folder.